# Appfabric Powershell error "The term 'Get-CacheStatistics' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.."

Tags: powershell, appfabric, powershell-cmdlet

I'm calling the simple following Powershell AppFabric command:

```
powershell -noexit c:\scripts\ApplyClusterConfig.ps1
```

and the script just contains:

```
Get-CacheStatistics
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
The term 'Get-CacheStatistics' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, funct
ion, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\scripts\ApplyClusterConfig.ps1:1 char:20
+ Get-CacheStatistics <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CacheStatistics:String) [],
    CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've done everyting that I can find on the web including

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

and using the .\  to refer to the file:

```
powershell -noexit .\ApplyClusterConfig.ps1
```

and setting the environment path to include c:\Scripts

But the error keeps persisting. Can anyone help please because I've run out of all google options. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As the errors says, it is not able to find `Get-CacheStatistics` as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. You need to laod the necessary modules.

Look here for guidance on how to load the necessary modules to run AppFabric cmdlets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677295.aspx

You will probably have to add one or more of the following imports ( maybe in your script):

```
Import-Module ApplicationServer
Import-Module distributedcacheconfiguration
Import-Module distributedcacheadministration
```

Execution policy has nothing to do with this error and you are running the script fine.

Comment: Yeah that worked, ran the command as follows:

powershell.exe -noexit -command "Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration;Get-CacheStatistics" 

Thank you